# Upgrade angular version 8 ---> 9

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, ng-upgrade

I want to upgrade my angular version 8 --> 9

Follow : https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l2, I wan to run this command : 
`ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8` and I get the error :

```
Package "ng-push" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

Exist a way to fix that whitout `--force` ? I think with force is dangerous. Any ideas ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to follow advance category [Angular update 8 > 9](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3). it has given you more visibility of what going to happen on update. after updating angular you may have to update third party libraries which is not compatible to angular 9. if you not sure what is going to happen , better to run `npm audit` and then `run npm audit fix`. i have used this way to update my solution to angular 9. Apart from that you me help these fixes depending on what you have done in your project
[ScrollDispatchModule not in angular issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18569) and
[The Angular @ViewChild decorator issue](http://:%20https://dev.to/angular/the-angular-viewchild-decorator-424c)

Comment: Can you say the reason for putting negative here.